# How does "Yo" ios app know when the user disables push notifications?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, apple-push-notifications

I am developing an app that requires push notifications. I would like to detect when it is enabled by the user and when it is not.

The famous "Yo" app immediately detects it when I disable push notifications from the iPhone settings !

How do they do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably with the following method:

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
BOOL enabled = application.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications;
```

You could potentially call this as often as you would like and even on a timer, and key-value observation of changes might work, although I haven't tested it.

Comment: This is a great way to check if your user has notifications. I suggest you see how Whatsapp handles that, it's pretty sweet. If  you disable it, you'll have a different screen at the start, say, after a couple of weeks, which asks you to go and reactivate it. You can of course dismiss the screen but it's a nice way to smoothly get your users back into your notification pool

Comment: @Peter,  this only works on iOS8. Do you have an idea on how does Yo do on iOS7 ?

Comment: I think like this: `UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes]` You can branch on the OS version I suppose.